# When is Spring Data MongoDB targeting support for MongoDB 3.0?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Seems the MongoDB release is a significant performance upgrade - ay idea when Spring Data MongoDB will support this version?

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, the MongoDB 3.0 server can even be used with the latest 2.13 Java driver and thus the currently released Spring Data MongoDB 1.6.2. For a full compatibility overview of the driver and server versions, see this [wiki page](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/).

The [recently released](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/05/spring-data-release-train-fowler-rc1-available) first release candidate of Spring Data MongoDB 1.7 ships support for the MongoDB 3.0 Java driver. This is mostly a compatibility release, we don't target special 3.0 features yet (although you should be able to benefit from an upgrade nonetheless).

Find more information about this in [the release train wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Fowler#rc1-3), the [JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1158) as well as the [corresponding section of the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.7.0.RC1/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-3).

The GA release of Spring Data MongoDB 1.7 is scheduled to be part of the Fowler release train GA end of March.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Mongo has 1.7RC1 -> http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.7.0.RC1/ Hopefully that one will be released soon.

As Java Driver github repo says, they released a 2.13.0 version on January 29th and it is stable -> https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/releases/tag/r2.13.0 It includes all the features for mongo 3.0, but you need to go through the compatibility to upgrade to this version.

Also, they are working on v. 3.0.0. for Java Driver, you can find it here -> https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/releases/tag/r3.0.0-beta3 (its still in beta though)